# Is it acceptable to edit an answer in ways that fundamentally change it?

Tags: discussion, edits

Maybe the wording of my question indicates that I think the answer is "no".

I've had a number of my answers "edited" in ways that practically substituted what the editor thought was the right answer for what I had written. My point isn't to gripe or to attack the people making these edits, and so I'm going to avoid giving the specific examples. (Which, I suppose, could make this post vague, but whatever.)

I think edits are appropriate if someone mis-spells a word or has a grammar error where the original intent was obvious or has a syntax error in a code sample. Some of my posts have been edited to turn free-form text into a neat table or other visual formatting, and I have no objection to that.

But I've had a number of cases where someone deleted or changed text from an answer because they thought it was incorrect or irrelevant. Whether they were right or wrong, what's left is now someone else's idea of the right answer with my name on it, and I find that pretty annoying. Especially if they're wrong, as they're now putting inaccurate statements in my mouth. Even if they're right, I'd prefer to take the blame for my own mistakes.

It seems to me that if you don't agree with someone else's answer, you should write your own answer, not change theirs. Or if you disagree about a minor point, post a comment expressing your disagreement, so other readers can see the original statement and your objection, and if it's debatable, maybe hear both sides.

Comment: If they are correct, and they've decidedly improved your answer, I can't see how this is a problem. If they are wrong, and you disagree, then they shouldn't have done it. Oh well, we have a feature in place for that—simply roll back the edit.

Comment: *"what's left is now someone else's idea of the right answer with my name on it, and I find that pretty annoying"* - +1. For what its worth, I'm pretty narrow in what I approve when it comes to modifying someone else's answer - spelling, udated links, etc. I'm not very tolerant of adding text, removing text, changing meanings, etc.

Comment: I don't mind rewording an awkward or possibly ambiguous phrase for clarity, or generally improving formatting/layout.  But changing the underlying meaning - especially when it's 'signed' by me - would be going too far. There are other ways to disagree with me - comments, posting your own answer or downvoting.

Comment: It is not simply "signed" by you. Your user card is there as the original contributor, but the editor is listed at the bottom center as well. What is more, clicking on that editor's information will present you with a *full edit history*. There is little risk of someone confusing your contributions with those of an editor. I'm surprised to see people expressing such selfish and protective sentiments. This website is *collaboratively edited*, like a wiki.

Comment: To me it seems as there is some confusion about where to draw the line between editing and reauthoring an answer. As I mentioned in my own answer below there are clear rules to how and when you should edit an answer. Even if it's true that one can roll back an edit to a previous state one should ponder about whether to edit an answer at all if it is considered to be of poor quality.

Comment: Those robo-reviewers at work again!

Comment: @Cody I could not disagree more. It's not about being selfish or protective. It's about encouraging different answers and letting users decide which one is best via votes. 

Yes, I can edit a question Cody writes to something I feel is more correct. Yes he van roll back if he disagrees. In the end though we have one answer to vote on when , in a sense, two different answers are provided (edited and original)

If BOTH answers were provided as answers then the community can decide via votes which one is better (as it should be). Keep edits for spelling and formatting. Not for altering answers.

Comment: @Paul So you don't buy into the whole wiki format thing, eh? This isn't a blog.

Comment: Nope it is not a blog. Nor is it a wiki. It is stack. Where "Good answers are voted up and rise to the top".

Comment: Yes, the point is supposed to be to serve the community. But there's also some pride in authorship that I think is valid. I'm sure we've all felt a certain amount of pride when we see an answer of ours get many upvotes. Sometimes when I see one of mine get lots of votes -- or get very few votes compared to what I consider a poorer answer -- I have to remind myself that points are not redeemable for cash, so why do I care? But I think it's fair to say, "This is my work, if you don't like it, don't tamper with mine, write your own."

Comment: I wouldn't say 'don't tamper with my work' but rather 'don't amend my opinion because you disagree with it'. This site is a resource, and so good answers should get voted up - and where relevant, amended for clarity.

Comment: links to examples or it never happened!

Comment: I think, none should have edited your answer for answer correctness purposes, up- and downvoting are the mechanisms to regulate that in SO.

Answer (score 52):

They should absolutely not change your answer in an extreme way. If they have a problem with your answer and believe it is incorrect, they have the ability to downvote it, submit a new answer, or comment.

Any edits that are not in line with what you want to say in the answer should be rolled back since it's ultimately your answer. If they get to be annoying, continuing to change the answer, simply flag the post with a custom moderator flag and explain what has been happening.

Answer (score 31):

Do the thing that will most benefit other readers of the question and answer.  If that means making a minor change to an existing answer to bring it more in line with the question, then do that.

But generally speaking, it's better to post your own, complete answer rather than significantly change the meaning of an existing answer.

Comment: How is that a benefit? When I look at a question, I want to see one complete, correct answer. That's kind of the whole point of this site. It doesn't do me any good to have a bad answer, a slightly incorrect answer, a slightly less incorrect answer, and a mostly correct answer. *Especially* when the mostly correct answer has already received a bunch of upvotes and will be near the top for some time, it's better just to fix that answer.

Comment: @PaulBinder **If the answer is not completely correct without altering it then it benefits readers most to post a new question.** Did you mean that it benefits readers to post a new *answer*?  If you post a new question, you're also depending on readers *finding* that question.

Comment: @Cody Gray if the most popular answer is wrong then it can be downvoted. However this relies on all users diligently scrolling through the answers, trying them all out, judiciously checking for mistakes then deciding which is best and upvoting it, downvoting other answers. So not going to happen!

Comment: @CodyGray when you look here http://stackoverflow.com/tour it does not  say anything about having one complete correct answer. It shows multiple answers with the BEST rising to the top. I don't see where it states the point is to have ONE complete correct answer? If that was the point then other less complete answers would be deleted by mods regularly.

Comment: @PaulBinder I should have used quotation marks to make my question clearer.  In your comment, you wrote that (emphasis added), "If the answer is not completely correct without altering it then it benefits readers most to **post a new question.**"  Did you mean "post a new answer"?

Comment: If the answer is not completely correct without altering it then it benefits readers most to **post a new answer**. This provides readers a firm compassion between a 'correct' answer and 'incorrect' one. Or perhaps different options to complete the same task. It also , if correct, becomes validated by the community with up-votes. The answer that is slightly incorrect (or fully) will receive less up-votes or even down-votes. If a reader was attempting the less correct path they would now be assured that this is the wrong way to go.

Comment: @CodyGray At the very least, this assumes that the person making the edit knows more than the person who wrote the answer that got a ton of upvotes. What if the editor is wrong? Then someone reading the answer will say, "Oh look, this answer got 100 upvotes, this must be right". When in fact the answer that got 100 upvotes said something very different, then someone else came along, substituted his own answer for the original, and hijacked the 100 upvotes.

Comment: @CodyGray "It doesn't do me any good to have a bad answer." Well true, of course. But the whole point of this site is that many people offer answers and others can rate which are good and which are bad. If we all trusted that you or whomever know all the answers, then we wouldn't need this whole system of multiple answers and voting. People could post questions, you could answer them, and we'd be done.

Answer (score 17):

Fixing cosmetic issues - even to the point of using different wording to improve clarity - is fine. Changing the meaning of what you wrote is not. I have no problem if someone wishes to disagree with my opinion, via comment, posting their own answer or down voting mine.

But I'd consider amending 'my opinion' such that it matched theirs would be unacceptable. Thankfully, you can roll back the edit.

Answer (score 11):

I'd say no. If someone assesses an answer needs such edits they really should consider posting a new answer on their own. The [rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) when editing questions and answers are quite clear on this...

Some common reasons to edit are:

- to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes
- to clarify the meaning of a post **without changing it**
- to correct **minor mistakes** or add addendums / updates as the post ages
- to add related resources or hyperlinks

If an answer contains poorly researched contents or isn't helpful to the community it could be downvoted or flagged - not edited. Improving an answer with edits is not the same as reauthoring the entire post.

Answer (score 5):

There is no legitimate reason to substantially edit an existing answer to change its meaning ...*unless* it has been upvoted and accepted--and seems to be undisplaceable through conventional channels.

I can see why one might feel editing a question sitting in the "this is the answer" slot might seem like the only recourse to the disenfranchised who are kept up late because ["Someone is wrong on the Internet"](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/duty_calls.png).  What I might suggest would be:

- Try adding your own answer first, and leave a comment on the answer linking to it in which you make your case for the correct answer.  Take note of the last login time of the answerer, and if it was 3 years ago don't be surprised if they don't get back to you.
- If that fails, bounty the question as "needs more attention".  I've done this and explicitly mentioned in the bounty reason that I want people to compare the accepted answer with mine and help with the incorrect information.  *(Unfortunately, if you've added your own "correct" answer then it's hard for someone new to come along and answer it to get a bounty; it might be nice if you could bounty a comment!)*
- If that doesn't work, try editing the answer while logged out (if you have non-reviewed-edit-powers).  That will bring it into the review queue and if it's accepted then at least you're not doing it unilaterally.  Lobby people on chat channels or social media to correct the injustice by voting.
- If none of this works and you still find the unsuitable answer is more importantly wrong to you than anyone else, edit it and deal with the consequences.  This is war, after all.

And there is an "other" flag for "needs moderator attention".  I guess you could use it to say "this accepted answer is misinforming people and too high ranked due to reasons of history (or otherwise)."  Ultimately having misinformative content on StackOverflow hurts StackOverflow's ablity to [fill the snack room with jars of money](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/a-new-name-for-stack-overflow-with-surprise-ending/).  If it's as wrong as you think, someone should fix it.

But no...don't rewrite someone's answer to mean something else, unless you need to save the world from unspeakable evils.

Comment: I basically agree with everything you wrote. If you do have edit powers, though, and the answer is old but wrong and the author is non-responsive, I think it may be acceptable to edit a note about possible errors into the answer, as long as it's formatted in a way that makes it clear that the additions are not the author's.

Comment: Some interesting points, though I would raise the quibble that what you are suggesting undermines the whole "up-voting" concept. The idea is supposed to be that if Al writes a good answer and Bob writes a poor answer, that Al's will get upvoted and Bob's won't. But if Bob is just convinced that his answer is better despite the fact that the community overwhelming thinks Al's is better, he can edit Al's answer to turn it into his -- at the extreme, substitute his own answer for Al's, but let's say more realistically change one or two key points where he thinks Al was wrong -- and now ...

Comment: ... the top-voted answer is not the one that the community thought was the best, but rather the one that Bob thought was the best DESPITE the community. (Yes, I can see scenarios where Al's answer was the best that could be given at the time he posted but new versions of the compiler make it out of date, etc.)

Comment: Flagging for mods is never the way to get rid of a bad answer—it'll just earn you a flag decline.

Answer (score 2):

I <s>sometimes</s> seldom *do* quite substantial edits to wrong/misleading parts of answers that are correct elsewhile.

My criteria for this are manifold:

- The answer must offer the correct solution in its general tone
- There is a large part of the answer that is exceptionally good, e.g. the explanation of the solution, that I don't want to copy/reproduce in a new answer but that is required for a complete answer (I know, I'm lazy).
- I assume that the answerer knows the correct solution and only made a lapse, and could've fixed the issue himself if I had commented about it. This means I'm not doing this to people that I haven't seen around in my area of interest.

I hope to not offend the poster by putting my content under their name, and don't mind if they rollback or improve my edit. If they do, I go to comment/downvote/write my own answer.

Comment: I wish there was a means of offering a suggested edit *for the attention of the original poster*.  In some cases where an apparent typo causes a sentence to say something other than what the author probably intended, making a proposed edit may be easier than trying to describe it in a comment [in the third sentence of paragraph three, did you mean "not" rather than "now"?], and examining a proposed edit and clicking "approve" may be easier for the OP than reading the comment, figuring out what it's talking about, and then editing the post, but if the author did in fact mean "now"...

Comment: ...then having the author edit the post to make clear that it meant "now" would be better than having the post edited to say "not", without the author's involvement and contrary to his intention.

Answer (score 2):

I say the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) states it perfectly :

```
Use edits to fix mistakes, improve formatting, or clarify the meaning of a post.
```

we should

```
1) Fix Mistakes (Mistakes the poster of the answer made on their post) 
2) Improve formatting 
3) clarify posters meaning
```

none of this states to change the answer or the intent of the answer.

Comment: The problem is that "fix mistakes" can be quite loosely interpreted.