# Prevent edits of accepted answer (by author or anyone else)

Tags: discussion, edits, accepted-answer

Why can an accepted answer be edited? It may confuse other people who want to use that code or try the answer. It's not a bad idea to update the answer, but editing or changing the whole answer is different; the first accepted answer should remain the same as before.

---

(The suggested duplicate [Is it acceptable to edit an answer in ways that fundamentally change it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269353/is-it-acceptable-to-edit-an-answer-in-ways-that-fundamentally-change-it) discusses extreme edits that change meaning of the answer, while I want to discuss why editing of accepted answer is allowed at all)

Comment: Link? Did the user remove their code or vandalize their answer? Did they improve it? Context?

Comment: Why shouldn't the author of the accepted answer be able to edit it? If, for instance, they notice an error in the answer, it would potentially be very confusing to leave it uncorrected.

Comment: Sometime the answer may contain [obsolete information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289061/best-way-to-use-php-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-passwords), or spelling mistate or whatever. Don't understand why you're so shocked by that (_?!_)

Comment: Generally people will edit to improve their posts not make them worse.

Comment: Not a bad idea to update the answer, but edit or change the whole answer is diffrent. I mean the first accepted answer should remain the same as before

Comment: Do you have a link to a specific case that inspired this question?

Comment: @HamidGoodarzi Why? You can see previous versions in the history. If the code was vandalized, roll back. If not, I assume that the answerer had a good reason to change it. You could ask why it was changed in the comments.

Comment: Note that people other than the answerer can edit answers, whether accepted or not, and you can see those edits in the post's history.

Comment: So you are saying it is ok to "update the answer" but not "editing the answer"? Sorry, I don't understand what that means. Could you please [edit] question to clarify what you consider ok and what not. (I.e. there is no "update" action, only "edit")

Comment: as others have mentioned there are legitimate reasons for editing any answer, including accepted ones. depending on who made the edit it may have been a suggested edit which had to be approved by either 2 users or the post author. however **without a link to the answer/edit in question** we can't tell if the edit is justified or not

Comment: I've update post a bit and voted to re-open as request here is different than suggested duplicate. So far I don't see any good reason to support this request but I think it deserves separate "no" answer.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov however what the OP is implying is that the edits they are talking about appear to alter the accepted answer so that it's completely different - *"It's not a bad idea to update the answer, but editing or changing the whole answer is different;"*

Comment: Why can they be edited? Because *the entire site* is collaboratively edited *by design*. It is only natural that accepted answers should be edited. Why *shouldn't* they be? Why should they be treated differently than any other answer?

Answer (score 7):

Wait. We have serious problems about accepted answers with not only obsolete information, technically inaccurate, but also [serious insecure ones](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293930/792066), which for better or worse, stick to the top and are the thing most people see first when they come from a search engine... and you want to prevent edition, the only thing that prevent us from being your good old forum/blog. That's not gonna happen.

I've made extensive reviews on my answer, specially if I find that my solution was suboptimal and found something better (in the cases where I have no better solution or the superior solution was already posted, I just delete mine) and that's a Good Thing™. We have issues with authors that do not maintain their answer as the solution ages and you want the very sporadic that happens to be forbidden. That's not desired under any circumstances.

If you have questions about whenever you don't understand an answer, you can simply comment on the post. I doubt anyone will be confused if someone edits their answer, because answers are supposed to be self-contained independent solutions which answer the questions. As long as it still answers the question, everything is working as intended.

Comment: i wonder why everybody are so angry! -accepted answer means, i try that answer and it's work for me, people said we need edit for more clarification on answer; so you can comment, they said we want to update; ok add update to answer not changing the first accepted answer, they said by editing we try to improve the answer; maybe there is lots of way to do or solve that question, then i say try to write your own answer not edit an accepted answer. any way thanks for your reply

Comment: @HamidGoodarzi that's one of my gripes with meta lately. It had cornered itself into the worst position ever.